# jQuery spin function - specify 20% spin upon image click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a jQuery newbie - but have managed to modify a roulette wheel script to spin a "pie" image for a homepage I'm working on.

It works great - but the client also want to add an arrow on either side that will advance the pie one section upon click - so clockwise for one arrow, counter-clockwise for another.

Is there a way to specify a partial spin?

Any guidance is much appreciated! I'm trying to meet a ridiculous deadline and am struggling with this.

Here's the page: 
http://bluetabby.com/rr/index13.html

Here's the jQuery code so far - the functions I need to figure out are leftArrow and rightArrow:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        window.WHEELOFFORTUNE = {

            cache: {},

            init: function () {
                console.log('controller init...');

                var _this = this;
                this.cache.wheel = $('.wheel');
                this.cache.wheelSpinBtn = $('.wheel');
                this.cache.leftArrow = $('.leftarrow');
                this.cache.rightArrow = $('.rightarrow');

                //mapping is backwards as wheel spins clockwise //1=win
                this.cache.wheelMapping = ['Mitzvahs','Galas','Florals','Props','Weddings'].reverse();
                this.cache.wheelSpinBtn.on('load', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                     if (!$(this).hasClass('disabled')) _this.spin();
                });
                this.cache.rightArrow.on('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if (!$(this).hasClass('disabled')) _this.spin();
                });


            },

            spin: function () {
                console.log('spinning wheel');

                var _this = this;



                //disable spin button while in progress
                this.cache.wheelSpinBtn.addClass('disabled');

                /*
                    Wheel has 10 sections.
                    Each section is 360/10 = 36deg.
                */
                var deg = 1000 + Math.round(Math.random() * 1000),
                    duration = 6000; //optimal 6 secs

                _this.cache.wheelPos = deg;

                //transition queuing
                //ff bug with easeOutBack
                this.cache.wheel.transition({
                    rotate: '0deg'
                }, 0).delay(1000)
                    .transition({
                    rotate: deg + 'deg'
                }, duration, 'easeOutCubic');

                //move marker
                _this.cache.wheelMarker.transition({
                    rotate: '-20deg'
                }, 0, 'snap');

                //just before wheel finish
                setTimeout(function () {
                    //reset marker
                    _this.cache.wheelMarker.transition({
                        rotate: '0deg'
                    }, 300, 'easeOutQuad');
                }, duration - 500);

                //wheel finish
                setTimeout(function () {
                    // did it win??!?!?!
                    var spin = _this.cache.wheelPos,
                        degrees = spin % 360,
                        percent = (degrees / 360) * 100,
                        segment = Math.ceil((percent / 5)),  //divided by number of segments
                        win = _this.cache.wheelMapping[segment - 1]; //zero based array

                    console.log('spin = ' + spin);
                    console.log('degrees = ' + degrees);
                    console.log('percent = ' + percent);
                    console.log('segment = ' + segment);
                    console.log('win = ' + win);


                    //re-enable wheel spin
                    _this.cache.wheelSpinBtn.removeClass('disabled');

                }, duration);

            },

            resetSpin: function () {
                this.cache.wheel.transition({
                    rotate: '0deg'
                }, 0);
                this.cache.wheelPos = 0;
            }

        }

        window.WHEELOFFORTUNE.init();
});//]]>
```

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: If you're just trying to make the animation work/respond how you want, have you considered using a library like Greensock? http://greensock.com - I recommend watching this tutorial to understand it better: https://greensock.com/position-parameter

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with it - I'll check it out. thanks.

Comment: By the way LouisK - Greensock library is amazing! Thanks for pointing me to it!

Answer (score 0):

I looked through your code and figured out you are using transit.js to do the spinning animations.  Essentially, the object's css (transform "rotate") is being updated over a certain amount of time (like jQuery's animate).

You can extend your wheel of fortune object with spinright and spinleft functions (or whatever name you prefer), which you can bind to the keys/buttons that you'll create.  Your code would look something like this:

```
WHEELOFFORTUNE.spinright = function() { 

  // get current degree of wheel and convert to integer
  var degree = parseInt( this.cache.wheel.css('rotate'), 10 );  
  this.cache.wheel.transition( { "rotate": (degree + 73) + "deg" },1000 );
}

WHEELOFFORTUNE.spinleft = function() { 
  var degree = parseInt( this.cache.wheel.css('rotate'), 10 );
  this.cache.wheel.transition( { "rotate": (degree - 73) + "deg" },1000 );
}
```

Then you can bind these functions to buttons or call the functions directly in console:

```
WHEELOFFORTUNE.spinright()
WHEELOFFORTUNE.spinleft()
```

Note:  73deg looks to be about the amount that 1 section is, but you'll probably have to play around with the numbers.  You may also want to cache the degrees in your object as well.  You probably will also need to figure out a way to center on each section per button press.

Cheers!